# How to order bug reports by creation time

Tags: python, python-requests, bugzilla

I am currently querying Bugzilla as follows:

```
r = requests.get(
    "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug",
    params={
        "chfield": "[Bug creation]",
        "chfieldfrom": "2015-01-01",
        "chfieldto": "2016-01-01",
        "resolution": "FIXED",
        "limit": 200,
        "api_key": api_key,
        "include_fields": [
            "id",
            "description",
            "creation_time",
        ],
    },
)
```

and all I would like to add to my query is a method for ordering the bug reports. I have scoured the web for a method for ordering these results: ultimately, I would like them to be ordered from `"2016-01-01"` descending. I have tried adding the following key-value pairs to params:

- `"order": "creation_time desc"`
- `"sort_by": "creation_time", "order" : "desc"`
- `"chfieldorder": "desc"`

and I've tried editing the URL to be `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug?orderBy=creation_time:desc` but none of these approaches have worked. Unfortunately, adding invalid keys fails without error: results are returned, just not in sorted order.

Ordering and ranges (ie., `chfieldfrom` and `chfieldto`) were not in any of the documentation that I found either.

I am aware that a hacked method of gathering ordered results would be to specify a narrow range of dates to get bug reports from, but I'm hoping there exists an actual key-value pair that can be specified to achieve the task.

Notably, of course: sorting **after** the request returns in `r` is invalid, because the results in `r` do not contain the most recent bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
    "order": [
        "opendate DESC",
    ],
```

to your `params`.

**Quick test**

To see more easily that it works, just run something like this after you received the response in `r`:

```
    data = json.loads(r.content)
    bugs = data['bugs']
    times = [x['creation_time'] for x in bugs]
    print(times)
```

gives:

```
['2016-01-01T21:53:20Z', '2016-01-01T21:37:58Z', '2016-01-01T20:12:07Z', '2016-01-01T19:29:30Z', '2016-01-01T19:10:46Z', '2016-01-01T15:56:35Z',...
```

**Details**

If you are interested in the details: It looks like some fields in the Bugzilla codebase have different field names.

Take a look here https://github.com/bugzilla/bugzilla/blob/5.2/Bugzilla/Search.pm#L557:

```
  # Backward-compatibility for old field names. Goes new_name => old_name.
  # These are here and not in _translate_old_column because the rest of the
  # code actually still uses the old names, while the fielddefs table uses
  # the new names (which is not the case for the fields handled by
  # _translate_old_column).
  my %old_names = (
    creation_ts => 'opendate',
    delta_ts    => 'changeddate',
    work_time   => 'actual_tFile.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), *%w[rel path here])ime',
  );
```